# Formatting data for two sample t-tests on R

Tags: r

Suppose I have the dataset that has the following information:

1) Number (of products bought, for example)

```
1 2 3
```

2) Frequency for each number (e.g., how many people purchased that number of products)

```
2 5 10
```

Let's say I have the above information for each of the 2 groups: control and test data.

How do I format the data such that it would look like this:

```
controldata<-c(1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
```

(each number * frequency listed as a vector)

```
testdata<- (similar to above)
```

so that I can perform the two independent sample t-test on R?

If I don't even need to make them a vector / if there's an alternative clever way to format the data to perform the t-test, please let me know!

It would be simple if the vector is small like above, but I can have the frequency>10000 for each number.

P.S. 
Control and test data have a different sample size.

Thanks!

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use `rep`. Using your data above

```
rep(c(1, 2, 3), c(2, 5, 10))
# [1] 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

Or, for your case

```
control_data = rep(n_bought, frequency)
```